# Emergency Mode Error on Startup

Tags: centos, startup

I boot up my CentOS 7 PC and on startup, it shows me this error (see image) - if I press CTRL+D, it boots up fine. Is there a way to clear this message or default it to starting up normally because the entire computer works fine, just after CTRL+D. See image below:

[image]

**The `journalctl -l -xb` log can be found at the LINK below because there was too much text entered:**

[CLICK HERE TO SEE JOURNALCTL -L -XB FILE](https://justpaste.it/3g86k/pdf)

**My `/etc/fstab/` file:**

```
#
# /etc/fstab
# Created by anaconda on Tue Dec 11 14:28:31 2018
#
# Accessible filesystems, by reference, are maintained under '/dev/disk'
# See man pages fstab(5), findfs(8), mount(8) and/or blkid(8) for more info
#
UUID=4d48ab0d-e1ab-4d7e-9f64-8481a7690060 /                       ext4    defaults        1 1
UUID=a7fad550-81d7-4150-8b76-e89584e4cfdf /boot                   ext4    defaults        1 2
UUID=0baabbc4-2dc0-4971-9d2b-c123e5ad7355 /home                   ext4    defaults        1 2
UUID=7756eafb-382c-46b3-aae8-e44d7e2cfe06 swap                    swap    defaults        0 0

~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~
```

Thanks @terdon - does this help?

I've also run `systemctl default`, `systemctl reboot` and `reboot`.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the logs as the error message suggests? I can see two errors reported, but can't tell more since you're not providing any information. Please [edit] your question and add some relevant details from the logs. Also, please show us your `/etc/fstab` file, looks like you might have an issue with one of the tmpfs mounts.

Comment: @terdon I'll have a look at that for you - all I need to know is how to dismiss/clear/sort it because it's not affecting the machine's running.

Comment: Yes, well the way to stop getting an error is usually to fix whatever is causing that error. Which is why the logs would be relevant to figure out what is actually happening.

Comment: @terdon - Should I just take a picture of the output from `journalctl -xb`?

Comment: No, [please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/22222). Instead, paste the text directly into your question and use the [formatting tools](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to format it as code. Don't forget to also include your `/etc/fstab` as I asked you yesterday.

Comment: You said you can boot your system correctly if you hit Ctrl+D, so do that and then run `journalctl -xb` and `cat /etc/fstab` and add the output to the question.

Comment: @terdon - I've uploaded my journalctl -xb log and my /etc/fstab file.

Comment: A second one of my CentOS7 machines are now having the same problem so If you can see anything wrong here, I could have a look on the other machines because the same problem is reported. @terdon - If anything needs editing, just respond with what to add/remove or change and I will `vim` it. Thanks - @terdon.

Comment: Your `journalctl -xb` is cut off in two ways: first, every line is truncated at 80 characters, so after the timestamp, hostname and message source, there is only the first 20 or so characters of each actual message. Some versions of `journalctl` require adding the `-l` option to get the full length of each line. Second, you've pasted just the first 23 lines of the actual output, and there should be much more. By default, `journalctl` displays its output using a pager, so please use `journalctl -l -xb` and get all the pages (press space to get the next page).

Comment: @telcoM please see the updated question with a [LINK](https://justpaste.it/3g86k/pdf) to my `journalctl -l -xb` file.

Comment: @terdon Please see the updated question with a [LINK](https://justpaste.it/3g86k/pdf) to my `journalctl -l -xb` file.

Comment: @telcoM Does it help?

Comment: @terdon Does it help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are still cut-off lines in your log output file, but the log confirms the problem happens while the system is still running in initramfs mode (i.e. early in boot, before mounting the real root filesystem).

So the problem seems to be not related to how your actual `/etc/fstab` file is set up right now, but it might be caused by how it **was** when your current kernel package was installed, as at that point a number of configuration files are packaged into the initramfs file. Or it might be because of some other error in the scripts used as components of your initramfs file, or the system running out of disk space while it was building your initramfs file.

Fortunately, rebuilding your initramfs file is easy. First backup the old one:

```
cp -p /boot/initramfs-$(uname -r).img /boot/initramfs-$(uname -r).img.bak
```

Make sure you're not running out of disk space in `/tmp` or `/var/tmp`, then tell `dracut` to create a new one for you:

```
dracut -f
```

Any messages at all are going to be indications of problems - if `dracut` works for a while and produces no messages at all before the prompt returns, it was successful.

Comment: Thanks but no luck - did both commands and they ran without any problems. Rebooted and still get the same error appear. - CTRL + D still boots up though. Any suggestions?

Comment: You might want to look for the word "huge" everywhere under `/etc` and `/usr/lib/dracut` to see where it might be coming from: `grep -r '^[^#]*huge[^pt]' /etc /usr/lib/dracut`. This command will look for uncommented instances of the word "huge" that are not parts of words `hugepages` or `hugetlbfs`. You may get some false hits (e.g. `/etc/mke2fs.conf`) but the results might give some clues on where to look.

Comment: Thanks but what do I do when I get a hit?

Comment: If you don't know, please add the results to your question so we can see it too. But if it turns out the results remind you of something you've done earlier and know how to undo (and suspect it's relevant), you could try undoing that change, possibly recreating the initramfs again, and then seeing if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Thanks - I'll have a go in a bit and let you know the outcome. - O

Comment: can you help with this? [LINK](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/591250/change-write-permissions-on-samba-share-mount-centos7)